# What does Number of tasks vs task memory vs task CPU do (AWS ECS)

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ecs

I'm new to AWS ECS and curious what the practical differences between number of tasks, task memory, and task CPU is.

For example, if I raise the number of tasks, what will that actually do? Reduce downtime? What about raising task memory etc. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Not a real Stackoverflow type of question but in a nutshell. A task is made of 1 or more containers that are tightly coupled, share resources and scale together. The task is the unit of work and the unit of scale in ECS. Scaling tasks and assigning resources to task is an orthogonal discussion. You need to give a certain amount of capacity to a task for the task to be able to run the container(s) in it. Regardless how much capacity you assign to a single task, you can scale those tasks in and out according to the workload. A typical scenario (but not the only one) is an ECS service comprised of `n` tasks (where n is a number between a `min` and a `max`) behind a load balancer.

Comment: Gotcha, this makes sense. So what would adding tasks do? For example, if I was getting an issue where too much traffic caused a new task to provision, would this be caused by not having enough tasks? Or would it be that each task definition is not powerful enough? Thanks

Comment: It would be both. Say you have an ECS service configured with tasks that have 2 vcpu and 8GB of memory (the service is configured with min=5 and max=20). You could configure an autoscaling rule that says "scale out when CPU is > 70%" and that will add tasks (up to 20) until average CPU is below 70%. The size of the tasks need to be configured upfront in the task definition and its size depends on the application (e.g. best mix of resources for the app, how many transaction per task  you want to serve, etc). Very app specific.